# SSD Heat Performance

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I'm currently searching for a good boot drive for a desktop.  Is heat an issue for an SSD?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/348066/will-an-ssd-help-prevent-laptop-overheating/348076#348076 - for desktop drives, you will see a reduction in heat, but the amount of heat from hard drives is negligible compared to other system components (e.g. CPU, GPU, motherboard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if SSD produce less heat.  Not according to this:
http://benchmarkreviews.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=299&Itemid=60&limit=1&limitstart=11

But remember these are 2.5" SSD.  I bet 3.5" HDD would produce more heat.

**EDIT**

Yup, according to this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000748.html

3.5" HDD produce a lot more heat.  So if you are using SSD on the desktop, you don't even need a fan on it.

Answer (score 4):

SSD's produce less heat than a regular hard drive. So no, not really.

I would say that heat isn't an issue for regular hard drives either. Not in a desktop environment anyway.

Comment: Agreed, although my previous computer had silly hard drives, dual 15.3k rpm scsi disks that definitely increased my cooling load.