# I want ways to cool my laptop

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling

I am asking about ways to cool down my laptop.

It's been over heating from a while, I tried cleaning the fan but nothing worked.

Comment: What makes you think it's overheating and what's with the italic font?

Comment: @Ramhound First i'm new i don't know how to post correctly and second i think it's over heating because when i play games it shuts down

Comment: 1. What method(s) did you use to clean the laptop before this issue arose? 2. Make/model of laptop? 3. Operating system?

Comment: @Maxdha - If your computer shutdowns itself down.  You should edit your question to make that known.

Answer (score -1):

see my answer here with pics, may help [Will an SSD help prevent laptop overheating?](https://superuser.com/questions/348066/will-an-ssd-help-prevent-laptop-overheating)  it shows two laptop cooling pads See my answer here too for a usb cooling option . pics there too [How can I keep my laptop fan on the entire time?](https://superuser.com/questions/588764/how-can-i-keep-my-laptop-fan-on-the-entire-time)

Comment: @fixer1234   That's ok. And it is an answer I just haven't gone to those questions and copied pictures in. Anybody is welcome to downvote it, that's fine by me. The q might end up getting closed but the main thing for me is the questioner sees the answer i've given him. It's pretty clear from those two links and I don't want to duplicate. The answer here is linking the two bits of info together