# Harddisk 2"5 inch ssd heat issue?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSD Heat Performance](https://superuser.com/questions/16599/ssd-heat-performance)

I want to know if a SSD hard disk 2"5 is a magnitude hotter than a conventional mechanical drive.

Can I presume that a SSD hard disk is much faster then a conventional hard disk?

Unfortunately my laptop gets very hot.

Comment: Hard drives have lots of mechanical moving parts which use a fair amount of power and generate a fair amount of heat. SSDs don't have those mechanical issues - only electrical ones, which hard drives have too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are quite cool. And yes, they are faster.

Answer (score 0):

This site prints: 
Temperature: because they use flash memory, SSDs barely warm up at all.  The same isn't true of HDDs which can in some circumstances become as hot as 50 °C.

http://www.digitalversus.com/duels-battle-of-the-five-star-products-a966/hard-drive-technology-ssd-vs-hdd-ap677.html

The idea is that SSD does not have moving parts and consumes less power. Power consumption is mostly converted into heat. So power consumption equals heat generation. The actual temperatures depend on how well this heat is dissipated and the amount of surface available to dissipate.

Comment: For a desktop hard disk, maximum operating temperatures are 65 (or occasionally 70) centigrade. Although modern drives don't generate heat very quickly, they are often in a still-air zone within the case. Also, silicone rubber anti-vibration widgets tend to prevent heat being loss through direct metal-to-metal contact with the case. Heat can slowly accumulate - I've known drives to still be getting hotter after an hour. Unless you have good cooling, it's surprisingly easy to overheat your hard drives - they tend not to die instantly, but their lives can be dramatically reduced.

Comment: Laptop hard drives really *need* to run cooler - they probably don't have a huge fan blowing air past them.